# Program that searches a key word and prints the whole sentence present next to it

Tags: java

I want a program that takes a string as input than searches for a specific word from cartoons[k] and prints the string at cartoons[k][]. Here is the code

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        int k=0;
        String[][] cartoons = {
            { "Flintstones", "Fred is a bad boy."},
            { "Rubbles", "Barney rocks."},
            { "Jetsons", "George was president of America."},
            { "Scooby Doo Gang", "Scooby Doo where are you?"} };
                boolean found=false;

        for (int i = 0; i < cartoons.length; i++) {
          System.out.print(cartoons[i][0] + ": ");
          for (int j = 1; j < cartoons[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(cartoons[i][j] + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Enter name to search.");
        str=s.nextLine();
             while(k<cartoons.length){
            if(str.equals(cartoons[k])){
            System.out.print(cartoons[k]);  
                found=true;
            }
            k++;
        }
    System.out.println("Not found");
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem you are having?

Comment: You probably want to replace `if(str.equals(cartoons[k])){` with something like `if(cartoons[k].toLowerCase().contains(str)){`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use respectively `cartoons[k][0]` and `cartoons[k][1]`. An array of `String` is not a `String`. `String::equals` will always be false with an array as an argument. I have also fixed your loop exit condition below:

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
String str;
int k=0;
String[][] cartoons = {
        { "Flintstones", "Fred is a bad boy."},
        { "Rubbles", "Barney rocks."},
        { "Jetsons", "George was president of America."},
        { "Scooby Doo Gang", "Scooby Doo where are you?"} };
boolean found=false;

for (int i = 0; i < cartoons.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(cartoons[i][0] + ": ");
    for (int j = 1; j < cartoons[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(cartoons[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("Enter name to search.");
str=s.nextLine();
while(!found && k<cartoons.length){
    if(str.equals(cartoons[k][0])){
        System.out.print(cartoons[k][1]);
        found=true;
    }
    k++;
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```